# Can I get the value for community site's What's Happening web part with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, community-site

I need to generate some statistic reports for our SP2013 community site. Some of figures I need are "no. of discussion", "no. of replied" and "no. of members" which are already listed in the "What's Happening" web part.

Can I directly get this counters with PowerShell instead of calculating from "Discussion Board List"?